# Azure Data Factory V2 + Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I am trying to leverage Azure Key Vault to secure password for service account that moves data from on-prem SQL server to Azure Data Lake via Azure Data Factory.

I first created the Linked Service and hard coded the credentials. It works.

However, I want to store the service account secret (i.e. password) within Key Value, and according to the following [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault#reference-credential-stored-in-key-vault), I added the Azure Key Vault Liked Service and referenced credentials stored in key value.

Under Advance within the Linked Service, see image #1, Iadded the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "LinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "SqlServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "username": "<domain>\<account name>",
            "password": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "secretName": "<service account name>",
                "store":{
                    "referenceName": "https://<name>.vault.azure.net/",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "IRMYService",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I look at the final JSON within Linked Service, it doesn't appear correct (refer to final image below). Why is username and credentials showing up?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have missed the below part from that same link-

> Currently, Dynamics connector, Salesforce connector and a few newly
>   enable connectors support this feature. Expect more coming later. You
>   can check each connector topic on details. For the secret fields which
>   support this feature, you will see a note in the description saying
>   "You can choose to mark this field as a SecureString to store it
>   securely in ADF, or store password in Azure Key Vault and let the copy
>   acitivty pull from there when performing data copy - learn more from
>   Store credentials in Key Vault."

As of now `Azure Data Lake Store` doesn't support `Key Vault` integration. You can always choose - **managed service identity (MSI)** authentication which would not expose your service principal information's.

The same applies to `Sql Server` as well - you have to choose `Secure String` for using the `connectionString` & `password`.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported out of the box. The link you provided has also been updated to reflect this:

> Currently, all activity types except custom activity support this
>   feature. For connector configuration specifically, check the "linked
>   service properties" section in each connector topic for details.

[image]

For more, check the [docs for Data Lake Storage Gen 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store#linked-service-properties) and [docs for Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#linked-service-properties).